# 2 triangles causing CGAL error

Tags: cgal

I have a 100'000 facet stl file that throws a CGAL error when I try to render it.

Worked it down to the first 2 facets causing an error.

Any hint how the combination of these 2 facets are a problem for CGAL and how I could probably fix it? (I use python stl library to filter out my facets from a larger stl file I use as a base. So I might be able to modify the points coordinates?).

I get the error with F6 when I try to difference() these 2 triangles from a cube.
ERROR: CGAL error in CGAL_Nef_polyhedron3(): CGAL ERROR: assertion violation

```
difference() {
    import("outerShell_ml.stl");

    translate([-11.4,-9.8,-6.5])
    #cube(1);
}

solid outerShell_ml
 facet normal -0.685994 -0.514497 -0.514495
  outer loop
   vertex -11.440000 -9.540000 -6.400000
   vertex -11.259999 -9.780000 -6.400000
   vertex -11.320000 -9.719999 -6.380000
  endloop
 endfacet
 facet normal -0.665639 -0.554699 -0.499233
  outer loop
   vertex -11.440000 -9.540000 -6.400000
   vertex -11.620000 -9.360000 -6.360000
   vertex -11.740000 -9.179999 -6.400000
  endloop
 endfacet
endsolid outerShell_ml
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with those two faces. Could you provide a minimal example I can compile and run that is showing the crash?

Comment: Create a text file from the lower lines from "solid ... endsolid" and save it as "outerShell_ml.stl" file.
Now use the upper part "difference{..} as openscad script and it will show you the CGAL error when rendering the data (F6)